# Generic methods type inference

Tags: delphi, generics, type-inference

Let's say I have a class with two generic methods:

```
TMyClass = class
  procedure DoWith<T: class> (obj: T);
  procedure DoFor<T: class> ( proc: TProc<T> );
end;
```

Now, when I want to call either of these two methods with a specific type parameter, Delphi can infer the type for the `DoWith` method, so I can call it with either

```
MyClass.DoWith <TButton> ( MyButton )
```

or

```
MyClass.DoWith ( MyButton )
```

The Delphi Compiler will happily compile both.
But if I omit the type parameter in the `DoFor` method, the Delphi compiler complains about the missing type parameter:

```
MyClass.DoFor<TButton>(procedure (Button: TButton) begin .... end);  // compiles


MyClass.DoFor(procedure (Button: TButton) begin .... end);  // doesn't compile
```

Now my question is: Is this just a shortcoming of the compiler, or is there any logical reason (that I haven't figured out yet) that prohibits the compiler from correctly inferring the type for the `DoFor` method?

Comment: It looks like a limitation of the compiler. Generic type inference is very weak in Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it cannot infer `T` from a `TProc<T>`argument is that at that time `TProc<TButton>` is a constructed type without any information that it originally was a `TProc<T>`.

To do that it would have to infer the type from the anonymous method signature which does not work (I guess Barry Kelly could explain that better and I think he once wrote about the difficulties of lambdas and type inference in Delphi).

The only type inference the Delphi compiler is capable of is an argument of type T. Even with multiple arguments that does not work often and even less if you have more than one generic type parameters.

Edit: I found a comment where Barry explained a bit about the difficulties of type inference and lambdas in the Delphi compiler: http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/244/comment-page-1#comment-107

Comment: Thanks Stefan: Your answer gave me the missing bits to understand that there is a logical reason for this compiler behavior.

Comment: @iamjoosy I personally find this illogical. I'd prefer it if the compiler would infer the types much better. I see no reason why it could not do so. Plenty of other languages manage this far better than Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan At first I could not see any logic in the compiler bahaviour myself, hence my question here. But Stefan's answer opened my eyes by explaining how the compiler treats the expression: It constructs the actual types from inside to outside, thereby first constructing the anonymous function with the TButton type and then operating with this type in the surrounding procedure and at this point the compiler has "forgotten" that the anonymous function was constructed from the same type parameter T that decorates the surrounding function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is not to say that it could not be handled better, but it explains why the compiler has its problems in its current implementation.

Comment: @iamjoosy It seems to me, based on my usage, that the compiler is pretty crap at inference with generics. It's pretty much obvious that this is down to the way it is implemented. I personally don't find it insightful to say that the compiler is implemented in a way that means it is pretty lame. That is crystal clear from the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I suggest you read some blog posts from Eric Lippert where he explains how much effort it took them to implement proper type inference in the C# compiler but how it was worth it to make LINQ work. Then you will understand why this is very low priority for Embarcadero.

Comment: @Stefan I don't really agree with that. Sure it's hard, but that's really it isn't it. The text in your answer tries to explain the weakness of the compiler and to me seems to present it as if there is something inherent that means it can't be done. The reality is, that the answer should be, "it's hard to do and the Embarcadero developers decided not to solve the problem". By leaving the compiler in its current weak form they just propagate messy code all over thousands of code bases. There would be a huge return for getting this sorted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There would not. Many Delphi developers (unfortunately) don't even use generics (which is also related to other issues with the implementation of generics in Delphi), let alone type inference.

Comment: @Stefan Are you so sure. An awful lot of the questions here relate to generics. So I suspect they are quite widely used. I certainly think that any decent professional developer using Delphi will be using generics.

Comment: @David I am so sure because I talk to people that know. Also 1% of all Delphi tagged questions also have the generics tag. I would not call that an awful lot.

Comment: @Stefan OK, if you talk to people that know, that's good enough for me. You've convinced me.

Comment: @David I have to agree with Stefan about the usage of Generics. I am leading a local Delphi User group and when at our last meeting I gave a talk about Generics I was surprised to find out how many Delphi Developers don't use them even though they are on > Delphi 2009. If they use them then mostly in the form of the standard Generic containers.

Comment: I guess Delphi developers are in the same league as PHP developers then